How to create a wheel file from an already installed Python package not available on PyPI?
I have a Python package with a specific version installed in my virtual environment, but it has been removed from PyPI and I don't have access to its source code. I'm trying to create a wheel file from this installed package so that I can replicate the setup in another environment.
Here's what I've tried so far:
pip wheel --no-index --no-deps --wheel-dir ./ <my-package>
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement <my-package> (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for <my-package>

But it does exist in my virtual environment
pip freeze | grep <my-package>
<my-package>==<my-package-version>


Try looking for the original wheel/tarball file in the pip cache dir or try this answer. In general you will still need to reconstruct a setup.py or pyproject.toml that would mimic the definitions of the original, and sometimes this isn't possible especially if the package contains non-Python code that must be compiled as it may only work on your machine.
